# Autoboot Debian 9 live cd

Tags: linux, debian, livecd

I am trying to make live cd of debian-gnome autoboot with changing timeout from 0 to 1 in isolinux.cfg - the problem is i only have access to windows machines for now. Tried extracting (7-zip) and reassembling in ImgBurn but got checksum error from isolinux when booting;
perhaps I got it all wrong and should read on sth else? 
Thank you.